# Is there any commad for getting the list_channels along with queue name in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

**rabbitmqctl     list_channels     name   messages_unacknowledged    queue_name**

Actually I have declared three queues, so i need along with list_channels, queue name is there any possibility to get like above mentioned.  please let me know.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
rabbitmqctl list_consumers  -q
```

It gives the channel_pid per queue for all the consumers.